# Reload Ember Parent Model on Child Route Change

Tags: ember.js

I have a parent route that holds a series of tabs (which are child routes).

The parent route has a model that hits a JSONAPI endpoint for gathering data that is tangentially related to the data of its children.

The data that the parent route accesses can change fairly quickly, so I would like to update it whenever the user traverses between the child routes.

Is there a way to essentially re-resolve a model hook on a parent route each time that one of its children is transitioned to?

Have tried something similar to below, but reload doesn't seem to be a method available to the parent model.

Parent route

```
export default Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.store.findAll('parentData');
  }  
});
```

Child route

```
export default Route.extend({
  beforeModel() {
    this.modelFor('parentRoute').reload();
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking of, to bad it's not working. Are you sure that you get parentRoute right, did you checked with debugger that you have it accessible in beforeModel?

Comment: Yeah, I have access to it, but the object doesn't seem to have a reload method at this point in it's lifecycle. If it did, I think it would reload the child route as well unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

If you reload the parent model, the child route model will get reloaded as well, leading you into infinite loop of reloading.

Think the best way for you would be just to do findAll() on your child routes, and use that data instead of the parent route model.

Comment: Right, but then I have to feed that data back up to the parent template each time. It just seems cumbersome to pass data up with actions on each transition.

Comment: Well, you don't need to pass anything. The findAll method reacts to store changes, so when you do a findAll('parentData') in your child route, the parentData of your parent route will update as well.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use '**willTransition**' hook on parent route. Every children route transition will trigger parent route's willTransition hook, and it won't be fired when the parent route just initialize.

So it will be look like this:

```js
export default Route.extend({
    model() {
        return this.store.findAll('parentData');
    },
    actions: {
        willTransition() {
            this.controller.get('model').reload();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reload your parent route model using yourParentModel.reload() when you transition to child routes.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on a model that is a resolved promise.